# Turning an integer-valued semimetric into a smaller pseudometric by preserving the kernel and keeping the value at critical points

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set, and let $\mathfrak d$ be a *[semimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Semimetrics)* on $X$, namely, a non-negative function $X \times X \to \mathbf R$ such that $\mathfrak d(x,x) = 0$ and $\mathfrak d(x,y) = \mathfrak d(y,x)$ for all $x, y \in X$. 
We say that a pair $(x,y) \in X \times X$ is a *critical point* of $\mathfrak d$ if $\mathfrak d(x,y) \le \mathfrak d(x,z) + \mathfrak d(z,y)$ for every $z \in X$. We denote by $\mathrm{Crt}(\mathfrak d)$ the set of all critical points of $\mathfrak d$, and we take $\ker \mathfrak d := \{(x,y) \in X \times X: \mathfrak d(x,y) = 0\}$. Of course, $\ker \mathfrak d$ is a subset of $\mathrm{Crt}(\mathfrak d)$ and contains the diagonal $\{(x,x): x \in X\}$ of $X$.

> **Q1.** Assume $\mathfrak d$ takes values in $\mathbf N$. Does there exist a semimetric $\mathsf d$ on $X$ such that (i) $\mathsf d$ satisfies the triangle inequality (hence, is a *[pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Pseudometrics)*), (ii) $\ker \mathsf d = \ker \mathfrak d$, (iii) $\mathsf d$ and $\mathfrak d$ coincide when restricted to $\mathrm{Crt}(\mathfrak d)$, and (iv) $\mathsf d(x,y) \le \mathfrak d(x,y)$ for all $x, y \in X$? If yes, can $\mathsf d$ be defined so as to take values in $\mathbf N$ as well as $\mathfrak d$?

The answer to the above question is negative if we throw out the assumption that $\mathfrak d$ is $\mathbf N$-valued, as it can be seen by letting $X$ be the Cartesian product $\mathbf R \times \mathbf N^+$ and $\mathfrak d$ the function 
$$
X \times X \to \mathbf R: ((x,m),(y,n)) \mapsto \frac{4mn}{(m+n)^2} |x - y|,
$$
which is a semimetric whose set of critical points is precisely the diagonal of $X$ (whereas the only pseudometric on $X$ dominated by $\mathfrak d$ is the trivial one).

The question was initially motivated by an attempt I was making to modify a certain function to turn it into a locally invariant metric on the factorization monoid of a monoid $H$. Then I changed my mind and followed a different approach, but I'd still like to know the answer, were it only for the sake of curiosity.